# Get the element id of the Skype Chat window

Tags: javascript

we have integrated "Skype for Business" with our Application and included this URI

"im:"

This opens up a chat window to chat with the recipient. Is there any way through which i can get the id of this chat window that has been activated and populate a default message on to chat window using Javascript or Angular? First I need to get the element id of the chat window that is open and populate a message on this chat window. I know it is possible to do in powershell script the issue is when deploying on server the powershell will start the instance of Skype for Business running on server. We need person to person message rather than a Bot sending message. Any ideas please

Thanks & Regards
SR

Comment: Is `im:` a deeplink?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say im: <sip:> url